# Excel Concatenate Rows

Tags: excel, concatenation

I have this excel worksheet

```
A          B          c   
foo1       joo1       loo1
foo1       joo2       loo2
foo2       joo3       loo3
foo2       joo4       loo4
foo2       joo5       loo5
```

Now I *want* this

```
A          B                  c   
foo1       joo1, joo2         loo1, loo2
foo2       joo3, joo4, joo5   loo3, loo4, loo5
```

How do I do this, preferably with GUI?

Comment: Uff, I don't think that's possible that easily (and it also somehow destroys the purpose of separated data cells). The only thing I could think of is creating a makro that does that for you. May I ask if you need to do this more often, or just once, and in which case how much data is involved? (So that one can say if it is even worth the effort)

Comment: just once, ~4000 rows, with 1-5 duplicates in first row.

Comment: Are you looking for a coding solution?  If so, add tags for your preferred programming language (I did a lot of work with Excel files using C# and NPOI).  If not, asking your question on a site like http://superuser.com/ might be more appropriate.

Comment: I plan to move the data to a Mysql db. Maybe writing a query would be easier there.

Comment: What is the exact logic that dictates what group of (old) rows appears in what (new) row?

Comment: in the final table, the first column contains unique values. The other columns contain comma separated values (which i plan to explode in php)

Comment: The real solution is with VBA, but I think you're on the right track to move it first to your MySQL DB and then massage the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are willing to write a macro...

Click the first "foo1" cell and run this.  It will join the foo1's then the foo2's until it hits a blank cell.  If you've never written a macro before perhaps we can walk you thru it.

```
Sub JoinThem()
   ' Go until blank cell (first click at upper left of range)
   Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
      ' If this row macthes the next row
      If ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value Then
         ' Join first column overwriting the values
         ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value & ", " & ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1).Value
         ' and Join the second column too
         ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2) = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value & ", " & ActiveCell.Offset(1, 2).Value
         ' Since we placed the data into one row get rid of the row
         ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Delete
      Else
         ' Next row does not match, move down one
         ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
      End If
   Loop 
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Pete, Never written a macro prior. However from the looks of the code did something similar- Basically I applied a unique filter to the first column, copied the second column, deleted the copied cells, removed the filter, resorted the second column, reapplied the filter and so on --> until I had no more filled cells in second column. At the end of it, I had 5 columns sitting sideby side - then concatenated them. Came out perfectly -- it wasn't "programming" though! Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm glad it worked out and you could use my answer at least as a model.

Answer (score 0):

Glad you found a solution.  I'd have also recommended a pivot table.  No coding required, just drag & drop your fields into the Row box.  Then let Excel filter out the duplicates for you.

Answer (score 0):

Also you could use [Salstat2](https://code.google.com/p/salstat-statistics-package-2/), and the following steps

1- import the data by using the option **open** in the file menu

2- Into the script panel you should write

```
# getting the colums
res= group()
res.xdata=  [ grid.GetCol('A')]
res.ydata=  [ grid.GetCol('B'), grid.GetCol('C')]
res.yvalues= ['concat(B)','concat(C)'] # concat is a function used to concatenate the data
report.addPage() # adding a new sheet to put the results
for lis in res.getAsRow():
   report.addRowData( lis) # adding the results row by row
```

3- more information [here](https://code.google.com/p/salstat-statistics-package-2/wiki/PivotData)