# Excel VBA to concatenate data from multiple rows into 1 row

Tags: vba, excel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Excel Concatenate Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961436/excel-concatenate-rows)

I want to merge several rows of data into a single row with an Excel VBA macro, and for the output to be on a new worksheet, but I don't know where to start.  The data is fairly simple, and consists of a column of IDs and a column of products.  There may be multiple lines with the same ID if multiple products entries exist, so I'm looking for a macro to loop through the dataset and merge these multiple entries into one.  If the row is unique (i.e. there is only one product entry against that ID) then the row can just be copied to the output sheet without any merging.

The data looks like this:

---

```
ID          PRODUCT

1-10OOMD6   Product SKU1 (9000)

1-10PQFV3   Product SKU2 (7000)

1-10QSCSB   Product SKU3 (50)

1-10RWX7L   Product SKU4 (2)

1-10TKZQJ   Product SKU5 (1)

1-10UROIL   Product SKU3 (12000)

1-10UROIL   Product SKU7 (12000)

1-10UROIL   Product SKU8 (12000)

1-10UW6KU   Product SKU9 (1000)

1-10UW6KU   Product SKU10 (6500)

1-10W5HR9   Product SKU11 (80)

1-10XZWX7   Product SKU12 (1)

1-10ZRXVJ   Product SKU5 (70)

1-10ZV49V   Product SKU3 (250)

1-110RQQN   Product SKU13 (1)

1-110RQQN   Product SKU2 (600)

1-110RQQN   Product SKU14 (1)

1-110RQQN   Product SKU4 (600)

1-112DJ2N   Product SKU15 (5)

1-112EWRQ   Product SKU16 (3000)
```

---

And I want it to end up like this:

---

```
ID  PRODUCT

1-10OOMD6   Product SKU1 (9000)

1-10PQFV3   Product SKU2 (7000)

1-10QSCSB   Product SKU3 (50)

1-10RWX7L   Product SKU4 (2)

1-10TKZQJ   Product SKU5 (1)

1-10UROIL   Product SKU3 (12000), Product SKU7 (12000), Product SKU8 (12000)

1-10UW6KU   Product SKU9 (1000),Product SKU10 (6500)

1-10W5HR9   Product SKU11 (80)

1-10XZWX7   Product SKU12 (1)

1-10ZRXVJ   Product SKU5 (70)

1-10ZV49V   Product SKU3 (250)

1-110RQQN   Product SKU13 (1), Product SKU2 (600), Product SKU14 (1), Product SKU4 (600)

1-112DJ2N   Product SKU15 (5)

1-112EWRQ   Product SKU16 (3000)
```

---

So that each ID on the output sheet is unique.

A few points:

- I couldn't paste images, so to clarify: this is an ID: 1-10OOMD6, and this is a product: Product SKU1 (9000)
- The dataset is large, at least 35,000 rows
- The data isn't initially sorted by ID, but easily can be.
- It would be great to separate the products with a comma.
- I would like to output of the macro on another worksheet.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  This would save me an enormous amount of time!
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is a *programming QA* site. Show us your code and tell us where it breaks.

Comment: OK, will do.  Wasn't sure of the protocol here.

Answer (score 2):

As a starting point:
Use a dictionary - how this can be done, look at this article: http://www.techbookreport.com/tutorials/vba_dictionary.html

After that, just do something like that (Pseudocode, will not work as vba initially you have work to do):

```
Dim dict as new dictionary.

for i=1 to activesheet.rows.count
Dim Key= activesheet.cells(i,1).value 'get the unique product-id
Dim Product = activesheet.cells(i,2).value  'get the product-sku

If dic.exists(Key)=false then 'the heart of this program: if key doenst exist, add a new one, if it alreadys exits, append data
dict.add(Key, Product)
else
 dict.Item(Key) = dict.Item(Key) & " " & Product
end if

next

    For Each v In dict.Keys
      'write it to your sheet
    Next
```

I would guess that this approach is faster than the other one, simply because dictionaries are fast and it does not involve multiple find-loops.

Comment: I like. I hadn't gone down that path because I'd assumed that this was a one-off task and second because I've been caught out once before suggesting (not on this site) that someone use use another scrrun.dll object only to find that their excessively paranoid IT department had unregistered the thing on their machines. I've tended to shy away from it in answers ever since. But yes, your approach is more elegant.

Comment: Thanks Christian, I'll get out the VBA books.

Comment: Hi Christian,
I'm making some progress on the VBA code, but I'm stuck on the output.  Here's what I have:

'write it to your sheet
    For Each v In dict
        Debug.Print ActiveSheet.Parent.Sheets("Products"), dict.Item(ID) & dict.Item(Product)
    Next

Which produces a "Run time error 438"

Can you see where I'm going wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Can you post the code in your Question? As a comment, it is very difficult to read.
At a guess, the debug.Print statement looks weird, did you use "( )"?

Comment: Also: "ActiveSheet.Parent.Sheets("Products")" is weird, you could simply use Activeworkbook.Sheets("Products) - its shorter and more accurate. Or better yet define somewhere something like this:
Dim PSheet as Sheet
Set PSheet= Activeworkbook.Sheets("Products")
That is faster and better maintainable.

Answer (score 1):

iDevelop's comment is quite correct; the site encourages more "try and then post only when you get stuck" type questions. However I do know that it can be hard when you don't even know where to start!

Here's where I would.

First I'd put an extra column of formulas to the right of your products. The formula that I would put in cell C2 would be:

```
=COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A2)
```

which would then be copied down becoming

```
=COUNTIF($A$1:A2,A3)
=COUNTIF($A$1:A3,A4)
```

and so on. What's the purpose of this? It counts the number of ID codes which are the same as the row that you're on but which appear on an EARLIER row. If that number is >0 then you know that there was a previous occurrence of the ID code.

Next, I would build some code to iterate through the UsedRange of your sheet. Look at column C of each row. If it is 0, then simply copy the ID and description to the new sheet. If it's NOT, then use the Cells.Find method to locate the earlier entry in your target sheet, and append the description to that cell.

There are probably other ways of doing it but the code should be easy enough to write and run acceptably fast.

Give it a go and see what you come up with, and by all means post back if you get stuck. (Though I won't be around for a few hours since it's bed time here; plenty of other people around the world doubtless will, though.)

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your reply Alan.  I've had a play around with this and I do think I'll try and follow Christian's approach above.  I have, however, saved your formula which I am sure will be useful in the future.