# Copy data from sheet 1 to sheet 2 using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel spreadsheet. There are two sheets in this.

- **Sheet1:**

  - `Company`
  - `Department`
  - `Addressline1`
  - `Addressline2`
- **Sheet2:**

  - `Account`
  - `Department`
  - `Address`

I need to :

- Check till the last non blank row in `Company` column.
- Copy the `Company` data values into `Sheet2.Account`, `Sheet1.Department` into `Sheet2.Department`.
- Concatenate `Sheet1.Adddressline1` and `Sheet2.Addressline2`.
- Copy into `Sheet2.Address`  on clicking a button using VBA Macros.

code:

```
Sub Button1_click()
 Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Copy _
    Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("F2" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
 Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Copy _
    Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C2" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
 Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F2").Copy _
    Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B2" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
  Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("H2").Copy _
    Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("K2" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
 Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("I2").Copy _
    Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("K2:K200" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
  Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("L2").Copy _
    Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("M2" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("AO2").Copy _
    Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("I2" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
 Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("BF2").Copy _
    Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("J2" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
End Sub
```

Comment: This is done to death, just google your own title. Once you have tried something, you can always post back with a specific question.

Comment: This is what I could get.

Answer (score 0):

This code will check blank and copy data from Sheet1 to Sheet2:

```
LastEmpty = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B"+CStr(LastEmpty)).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
```

For concat look at:
[Excel Concatenate Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961436/excel-concatenate-rows)
and follow these tips.

For future please use search engine to resolve your problems and don't duplicate posts.