# Merge rows in Excel and separate with OR

Tags: vba, excel

At work I get Excel sheets pretty regularly that contain a column of numbers (which can be anywhere from 4 to 12 digits long). Sometimes I get a few, sometimes I get hundreds. I need to search for these numbers in an Isilon server using Windows Explorer (it is an SMB based server) which can handle roughly 50 numbers at a time.

The only way to do this right now is the old fashioned way - I copy 50 numbers from the column of numbers in Excel and paste them into Notepad. I then make all of the numbers one row and manually paste in between each number the OR function. So I end up with something like this (this is only 10 but it could be up to 50):

```
1266135 OR 1266197 OR 1266197 OR 1266197 OR 1266256 OR 1266256 OR 1266256 OR 1266418 OR 1266418 OR 1266418
```

I'm not that good with VBA, I rely mostly on what I can do with macros. Auto formatting a column of numbers to look like this for searching in Windows is beyond me. I have tried some of the things I've found here on Stack but the hardest part so far has been to place the OR function between each number.

Any suggestions on where to start? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3961436/62576). Instead of adding a comma, add ' OR ' instead. You can then (via macro or otherwise) export it to Notepad or wherever you'd like.

Comment: Have you tried like this: For instance if your numbers start on B2,B3 ... Then you can paste following code in C2 then drag it down until end of number =C1 & " OR " & B2 This way you'll get what you need on the last row

Answer (score 0):

In the same vein as one of the other commenters, I would recommend a function that would auto-generate the text you need for you (recursively) or a macro. However, if you'd like something you could just paste into a cell to get what you want, it would look something like

```
=CONCATENATE(A1," OR ",A2," OR ",A3," OR ",A4," OR ",A5," OR ",A6," OR ",A7," OR ",A8," OR ",A9," OR ",A10," OR ",A11," OR ",A12," OR ",A13," OR ",A14," OR ",A15," OR ",A16," OR ",A17," OR ",A18," OR ",A19," OR ",A20," OR ",A21," OR ",A22," OR ",A23," OR ",A24," OR ",A25," OR ",A26," OR ",A27," OR ",A28," OR ",A29," OR ",A30," OR ",A31," OR ",A32," OR ",A33," OR ",A34," OR ",A35," OR ",A36," OR ",A37," OR ",A38," OR ",A39," OR ",A40," OR ",A41," OR ",A42," OR ",A43," OR ",A44," OR ",A45," OR ",A46," OR ",A47," OR ",A48," OR ",A49, " OR ", A50)
```

(pretty long for 50)
Once you've done it once, you can take whatever cells you need by either dragging a cell with this formula down (to increment all the numbers) or replacing the "A" with another cell by dragging left/right (just offsetting the starting cell to whatever you want). The output of this cell is a set of 50 starting from the first listed cell in the formula and going straight down. This might be the most 'drag and drop' way to get the text you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a VBA version that joins all values from column A on Sheet1

```
Public Sub MergeVals()

    Debug.Print Join(Application.Transpose(Sheet1.UsedRange.Columns(1)), " Or ")

End Sub
```

---

Output: `1266135 Or 1266197 Or 1266197 Or 1266197 Or 1266256 Or 1266256`

Comment: Sounds great to me, but when I run this as a macro I get "Run-time error '13': Type mismatch"

Comment: There are some limits to the Transpose function: it can't handle more than 65,536 rows (2^16); you might also have problems if the text in cells is longer than 255 chars. If ether of these apply to you, make sure to update "Sheet1" to the code name of the sheet you want